# Can we set voltage/frequency for each GPU core(SM)?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

All GPU cores(SMs) have same voltage/frequency?
I am a fresh man in heterogeneous compution. I want to scale voltage/frequecy for each GPU SM, however,I do not know whether it is feasible.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? GPU computing is about tackling massively parallel problems via *throughput computing*, i.e. many cores/SMs performing the same task. Power is a [convex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) of frequency, so that the optimal throughput is achieved when all cores run at the same frequency. If you want maximum performance for just a few threads, run them on the CPU.

Comment: Anyway you are essentially getting the effect already - if your problem is not large enough to fill the entire GPU, the headroom in the power budget will be used to boost SM clocks. It's just not under your explicit control.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible.

There is not a separate voltage regulator per SM, nor is there a separate clock source per SM.

Comment: I have read some papers about heterogeneous's power optimization using DVFS,DCS,power gating,powering capping etal.I got confused.Thank you.